# How to get the key and value from dictionary

Tags: c#

I have dictionary like this :

```
"parameters": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "value": "b"
        },
        {
            "name": "c",
            "value": "d"
        }
    ],
```

Have defined the dictionary like this :

```
Dictionary<string, atypeModel>
```

where atypeModel is like this :

```
 public class atypeModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

now , what Im not getting is how to retrieve the value by key . I did below :

```
var myKey = types.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value == "b").Key;
```

but it is giving below error :

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'atypeModel' and
> 'string '

please suggest

Comment: You can't deserialize that JSON to a dictionary, because it's a list of objects.

Comment: This is terrible code in general, I suggest a rewrite! Please accept OMANSAK's answer and I hope you getting paid bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `var myKey = types.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value.Value  == "b").Key;`

your dictonary like as :

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "value": {
      "Name": "a",
      "Value": "b"
    }
  }
]
```

If you want this

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "value": "b"
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "value": "d"
  }
]
```

you should make `List<atypeModel>`

Comment: I cant change anything in the code. I have to just use the Dictionary and model as it is and get the keys and values

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value.Value  == "b").Key` use this.

Answer (score 1):

The word "Value" is used by "Dictionary" and also your class "atypeModel".
It may be a little confuse to use both "properties". I sugest you change your class "Value" property for "TypeValue" and then:

```
(...).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value.TypeValue == "b").Key
```

...just like OMANSAK said on comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can not deserialize above json into the form of `Dictionary<string, atypeModel>`. You need List in the value, because value of "parameters" is of type `List`.

First change your model to `Dictionary<string, List<atypeModel>>`.

Now once you change your model, now things are easy, just apply same logic on the `types["parameters"]`

Like,

```
Dictionary<string, List<atypeModel>> types = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<atypeModel>>(json)
var myKey = types["parameters"].FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value == "b").Key;
           //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This was missing
```